# WinUI 3 DropDownButton data binding

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

How to bind DropDownButton's items to a ViewModel?

```
<DropDownButton Width="100" Grid.Column="2" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Language">
    <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="Select language"/>
    <DropDownButton.Flyout>
        <MenuFlyout Placement="BottomEdgeAlignedLeft">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="English" Tag="enEn" Click="DropdownOptionLanguage_Select" />
        </MenuFlyout>
    </DropDownButton.Flyout>
</DropDownButton>
```

If we follow the logic here `MenuFlyout` or `DropDownButton.Flyout` is the container for items. But there is no `ItemSource` property or something what I can bind to an enumerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can add items in code-behind:

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<DropDownButton Content="Select language">
    <DropDownButton.Flyout>
        <MenuFlyout x:Name="SelectLanguageMenuLayout" />
    </DropDownButton.Flyout>
</DropDownButton>
```

```cs
public enum Languages
{
    English,
    Spanish,
    French,
    German,
    Italian,
}
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        foreach (Languages language in Enum.GetValues<Languages>())
        {
            this.SelectLanguageMenuLayout.Items.Add(
                new MenuFlyoutItem
                {
                    Text = language.ToString(),
                    Command = ViewModel.ChangeLanguageCommand,
                    CommandParameter = language,
                });
        }
    }

    public MainPageViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();
}
```

```cs
public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [RelayCommand]
    private void ChangeLanguage(Languages language)
    {
    }
}
```

I'm using the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty) NuGet package for the MVVM design.

**UPDATE**

This should be a closer approach to what you mentioned in the comments:

**MenuFlyoutEx.cs**

```cs
public class MenuFlyoutEx : MenuFlyout
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ItemsSource),
            typeof(IEnumerable),
            typeof(MenuFlyoutEx),
            new PropertyMetadata(default, OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Command),
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(MenuFlyoutEx),
            new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is not MenuFlyoutEx menuFlyoutEx ||
            e.NewValue is not IEnumerable itemsSource)
        {
            return;
        }

        menuFlyoutEx.Items.Clear();

        foreach (object item in itemsSource)
        {
            MenuFlyoutItem menuFlyoutItem = new()
            {
                Text = item.ToString(),
                Command = menuFlyoutEx.Command,
                CommandParameter = item,
            };

            menuFlyoutEx.Items.Add(menuFlyoutItem);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```cs
// This class needs to be "partial" for the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.
public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    // The CommunityToolkit.Mvvm will generate a "ChangeLanguageCommand" for you.
    [RelayCommand]
    private void ChangeLanguage(Languages language)
    {
        // Do your logic here...
    }

    // The CommunityToolkit.Mvvm will generate a "LanguageOptions" property for you.
    [ObservableProperty]
    private Languages[] _languageOptions = Enum.GetValues<Languages>();
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainPageViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();
}
```

and use it like this:

```xml
<DropDownButton Content="Select language">
    <DropDownButton.Flyout>
        <local:MenuFlyoutEx
            Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ChangeLanguageCommand}"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.LanguageOptions}" />
    </DropDownButton.Flyout>
</DropDownButton>
```

Comment: many thanks! 2 additional questions please: 1) why ViewModel inherits from ObservableObject but not from INotifyPropertyChanged? Is INotifyPropertyChanged already legacy technique? 2) Is there XAML solution like ListView or DataGrid has (DataContext / ItemSource binding)?

Comment: 1) I strongly recommend that you take a look at this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm-community-toolkit-features). The *CommunityToolkit.Mvvm* NuGet package has source generators that generates MVVM related code for you, including `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: 2) Updated my answer. Hope it helps.